# gwan reverse proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, g-wan

I am searching to configure gwan to act as reverse-proxy cache to my web python application.
I could'nt find some example on the web.

Thanks a lot for your examples

---

Laurent

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is merely to *accelerate* your Python application then you should just run it from G-WAN (see the [hello.py](http://gwan.ch/source/hello.py) example).

Some (advanced) users have used G-WAN handlers to write their own custom proxy, but G-WAN will document its `embedded proxy` (and load-balancer) in the following weeks.

It still works without configuration files, so you will not have to learn anything new.

And the competent users will like the ability to personalize the proxy with their own scripts.

There's always a long way between a solution that "runs" and a polished version ready for a wide public.

Comment: My own opinion, using python or ruby is ok only for basics stuff ...
If you have to load some libraries, connect to DB it will be too slow (because of ruby/python) not G-WAN

Comment: It all depends on where the bottleneck is: is it the script or the server? This is on a per-case basis (type of load, hardware, etc.).

Comment: I tried to run a ruby script which simply connect to a mongoDB server...
Loading necessary libraries (require "mongodb")consume too much time to load it. This is why ruby apps are using a rack adapter to run apps as a daemon and only load libraries at startup (not for all requests)

Comment: There is no end to the problems artificially created by using the wrong tool and architecture: not all language runtimes are able to work reliably under high concurrencies - and until it happens (maybe one day through unified LLVM implementations) high-performance applications must to the proper choices.